# How to position a div at the top of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, position

The first div is the `'#icon-selection-menu'` bar, it's idle position is *absolute* with `top:0px` and `left:0px`. So it appears at he top left corner inside the content div.

Deep in the content div children I got other divs which are actually kind of '.emoticon-button'. Their position is relative inside their parent. On such button click I'd like to position the first div just above the button, adjusting it's bottom border to the button's top border.

How can I get *top* and *left* values to set `$('#icon-selection-menu').top` and `$('#icon-selection-menu').left` ?

Comment: add relative css property for that display : relative ;

Answer (score 26, accepted):

jQuery<sup>1</sup> provides [**`.offset()`**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the position of any element relative to the document. Since `#icon-selection-menu` is already positioned relative to the document, you can use this:

```
var destination = $('.emoticon-button').offset();
$('#icon-selection-menu').css({top: destination.top, left: destination.left});
```

`$('#icon-selection-menu')` will be placed at the top-left corner of `$('.emoticon-button')`.

<sub>(1) jQuery assumed due to the use of `$` in the question.</sub>

Comment: 2nd line could be `$('#icon-selection-menu').css(destination);` couldn't it?  Or `$('#icon-selection-menu').offset(destination);`

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Yes!

Answer (score 7):

You can get the top and left position of a div using offsetTop and offsetLeft

Example:`

```
$('#div-id').offset().top;
$('#div-id').offset().left;
```

Comment: Thank you, Prasath! I voted up, but marked as the solution the other post as it is more detailed.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript has a built-in version of what @bfavaretto mentioned. It is a bit longer than the Jquery version, but people like me who don't use Jquery might need it.

```
var iconselect = document.getElementById("icon-selection-menu");
var emoticonbtn = document.getElementById("emoticon-button");
var oTop = emoticonbtn.offsetTop;
var oLeft = emoticonbtn.offsetLeft;
iconselect.style.top = oTop;
iconselect.style.left = oLeft;
iconselect.style.position = "absolute";
```

You can, of course, add units to this system such as px or other things. Just note that what I did above was just an example and is for two seperate elements with IDs, not classes. The first two lines of the code will vary according to your code. The element `iconselect` is what I am trying to align, and the element `emoticonbtn` is the button you press to make `iconselect` appear. The most important parts of the code summarized:

```
elementtomove.offsetTop; //distance from top of screen
elementtomove.offsetLeft; //distance from left of screen
```

Hope this helps the people who are unwilling to use JQUERY!

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

Comment: [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)

Comment: conselect.style.top = oTop+"px";
iconselect.style.left = oLeft+"px";

Otherwise it doesn't work and only applies the absolute property.

Comment: adding pixels or not still works. It is recommended that you do use px for more precise examples, but in this example is not necessary for it to work

Answer (score 0):

you can get the position of the element by using the below jquery

```
var position=$('#icon-selection-menu').position();
var left=position.left;
var right=position.right
```

and on click of that button you can position it above by using

```
$("#ID").live("click",function(){
    $('.emoticon-button').animate({left:left,right:right});
});
```

Comment: position() returns top and left inside the parent box, sorry that doesn't work to me. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Get '.emoticon-button' position(left,top). Then apply the same to '#icon-selection-menu'. There would some adjustment on top and left to align with emoticon.

Comment: position() returns top and left inside the parent box, sorry that doesn't work to me. Thank you for your advice.