# Hide iframe after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm using this code:

```
    <div class="youtube">
  some text and images
  <iframe width="500" height="370" src="http://youtube.com/ID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS for "youtube"

```
 .youtube{ 
   opacity: 0;
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80);
 }
```

I'd like to know if there is some way to, hide this *iframe* completely *after the first click*.

I'm really a beginner in programming, so detailed help would be great.

Comment: What do you mean after the first click?  The first click on what?

Comment: The first click on iframe

Comment: As soon as someone clicks on your video you want to hide it?

Comment: Yes if that is possible.

Comment: What do you mean by completely? You're already hiding it in your CSS regardless of any clicking. Do you only want that CSS to apply post click?

Comment: I just want that after the first click anywhere on the page where iframe is, that div to be removed out of the page. like hide it completely.

Comment: Have a look in this topic: [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111267/how-to-click-on-an-iframe-to-remove-it)

Here is the code
[fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/nT4uZ/7/)